# Tex Gyre Bonum font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, punctuation, tex-gyre-math

I'm writing a document using Tex Gyre Bonum as roman font and Tex Gyre Bonum Math as math font. But these fonts have different commas. So, commas in equation environments are not equal to commas in regular text. How can I make commas in math mode equal to commas in regular text?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,cancel,esint,mathtools,stackrel,stmaryrd,undertilde,amsfonts,siunitx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setromanfont{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}

\begin{document}

Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet, consectetur, adipiscing, elit. Fusce, vel, pellentesque, tellus. 
$$E=mc^2,$$
Nunc, ut, pharetra, mauris, quis, maximus, risus. Fusce, eu, laoreet, justo. 
$$,,,$$

This is comma in regular text: ,

This is comma in math mode: $,$

\end{document}
```

[image: PDF]

Comment: looks quite equal to me. Show a complete document.

Comment: I have added some LaTeX code that shows what I'm saying. I compiled it with LuaLaTeX

Comment: It's the fault of the italian option, it redefines the comma in math.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possible workarounds:

1. load the `dcolumn` package
2. use `polyglossia` instead of `babel`

For various reasons, `babel-italian` started to mess with commas in order to emulate the behavior of `icomma`. There is apparently no way to disable this without loading `dcolumn`, that avoids the mess to even start.

Also issuing `\AtBeginDocument{\NoIntelligentComma}` doesn't solve the problem, because this restores the mathcode of the comma to the value it has in legacy LaTeX and is not good for `unicode-math`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,dcolumn}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}

\begin{document}

Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet, consectetur, 
adipiscing, elit. Fusce, vel, pellentesque, tellus. 
\[E=mc^2,\]
Nunc, ut, pharetra, mauris, quis, maximus, risus. Fusce, eu, laoreet, justo. 
\[,\text{,},\]

This is comma in regular text: ,

This is comma in math mode: $,$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It shows the error `The font "TeXGyreBonumMath" cannot be found`.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Try with `\setmathfont{texgyrebonum-math.otf}`

Comment: Thanks, it works!!